# When you have an array of structs, is there a fast way to copy a single member of the struct into a different array of that members type? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I know you can simply loop on the indexes of the struct and the array, but is there something like memcpy that is faster?

Simple, but not that fast example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    double member1;
    unsigned int member2;
};

const int size = 100;
MyStruct arStructs[size];
unsigned int arUnsignedInts[size];

// ...Do initialization of arStructs here...

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    arUnsignedInts[i] = arStructs[i].member2;
```

Comment: Since your data is not contiguous (there is a `double` in-between) a loop is as good as you can get.

Comment: Not here. A good compiler could possibly use SIMD instructions to make this a bit faster if `MyStruct` has some padding at the end or if `sizeof(double) == sizeof(unsigned int)`. Note that in many cases it can be better to use structure of array rather than array of structure (especially for SIMD optimizations and cache efficiency)

Comment: You basically want to memcpy a non-continuous range of memory, leaving out every other `sizeof(double)` bytes? I don't think so. If this is important, you would want to drop your use of structs, and simply maintain one array of doubles, and one array of ints, [ie use SoA instead of AoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA).

Comment: `memcpy` does not work in all cases. E.g. if your type contains a `std::string`, things can get problematic. Whether there's actually a difference in performance for types where you can use `memcpy` is probably best tested...

Comment: Interleaved copies are notorious bottlenecks. There isn't much you can do, beyond considering your reasons for doing it in the first place. If it's just for convenience, you might want to rework how you process the data downstream. Sometimes you can roll the interleaving into symmetric processing steps, such that you ingest data in chunks and output the interleaved data at the latest possible time.

Comment: Every now and then you do find a usecase for multiple parallel arrays instead of a nice, clean array of a structure.

Comment: I recommend having the compiler print out the assembly language for your code.  Do this for different optimization settings and compare the assembly language listings.  There *may* be something you can do, but it may be negligible in time savings.

Comment: Have you tried unrolling the loop?  (The compiler may do this a higher optimizations.)  Unrolling the loop may have better cache performance, again, is the savings noticeable or measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Profile your version first to get a baseline.

Try loop unrolling:

```
for (int i = 0; (i + 4) < size; i += 4)
{
    const unsigned int a = arStructs[i + 0].member2;
    const unsigned int b = arStructs[i + 1].member2;
    const unsigned int c = arStructs[i + 2].member2;
    const unsigned int d = arStructs[i + 3].member2;

    arUnsignedInts[i + 0] = a;
    arUnsignedInts[i + 1] = b;
    arUnsignedInts[i + 2] = c;
    arUnsignedInts[i + 3] = d;
}
// Process the remainder(s)
for (; i < size; i++)
    arUnsignedInts[i] = arStructs[i].member2;
```

The goal is for the compiler to generate 4 reads from the array of structures into registers, then generate 4 writes from registers to the array of unsigned integers.  Hopefully, this will reduce the quantity of cache misses by loading registers from nearby entities. In your example, worst case is that the data cache is reloaded during each copy.  In my example, it reloads the cache every 4th copy.

Comment: I understand the idea, but 4 seems to me like a magic number... why don't you use 8 or 16 for example? Where is the cache limit? Or how to query the cache limit?

Comment: I picked 4 for illustrative purposes and quick typing.  You can choose whatever you like.  Look at the assembly code to verify you haven't run out of registers.